# using class from Jar file in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, java-native-interface, native

i have Jar file that implement class with static function that calling native code from dll.
i added the jar to classpach.
i am looking on the the class in the jar and it looks something like:

```
package com.aeroflex.afApplicationControlDll;

import com.aeroflex.jni.*;

public class afApplicationControl
{
    static
    {
        System.loadLibrary("afApplicationControlJNI");
    }
    public static native int GetServerVersion (int version[]);
    public static native int Initialise( int n1, int n2, int n3, int n4 );
}
```

In my class I am trying to use the class afApplicationControl

I am trying to import:

```
import com.aeroflex.afApplicationControlDll.*;
```

but the compiler do not found com.aeroflex.*

what is the problem?

Comment: *"im my class i am trying.."*  Try using your shift key.  It should be applied at the start of every sentence.  It should be applied for every use of the word I (or I'm etc.).
  It should be used for proper names like Java or for abbreviations like DLL.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that jar file is in your class path. Right click the project > properties> Lib, check your jar exist there. If so Please clean your project by select the project then click the "project"tab and  clean the project then try.

Comment: i right click on my project then properties>java build path>Libraries
and the jar is there.
i did clean with no help.
any more ideas?

Comment: Expand the jar check whether the package is present or not.

Comment: i think you are right!
i expand the jar. inside the jar there is package afApplicationControlDll. inside the package the is file afApplicationControl.class
how do i fix that?